# How to don't refresh table on each character typed - Material Table mbrn

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am having a trouble using the Material Table from mbrn. I will try to resume the problem as better as i can. Here it goes an image:

[Material Table used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEMUn.png)

I am using this table component. I am using remote data that comes from an API call. The problem is that on each letter that i type on each column filter, the table updates and call the API for refresh. I don't want that.

What i want is to let the user write the column filters that he wants and then click on the "Atualizar" button and when clicked the call to API with the filters and the refresh happens.

Anyone can help me to do it?

Comment: please share you code as well so I can guide you better way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, `useEffect()` with no dependency so it will get fetch data from API only one time when component render first time

```
useEffect(()=>{
     // api call or fetch data
},[])
```